# Repeating elements in list equal number of times

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice

I have some code that creates data, and then I want to sample the data.

My code first makes a series of vectors that have intervals drawn from a exponential distribution `z_exponential_layers` which then becomes `new2`.

I then take each `new2` vector and see how many times `dz` fits into the interval between each element in `new2`.

For example, if `new2 = [z1,z2,z3,...,zn]` then the second part of the code aims at finding how many times dz fits into each element in `[z2-z1,z3-z2,...]`. So if `(z2-z1)/dz = 5 = repeats` then I will store in a list `vec += [np.random.normal(0,1)]*repeats` and then move to the next interval.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z_max = 100
dz = .01
#Intensity of process
lam = 0.1
#Number of rays
rays = 10
k = int(z_max/dz)
print('k =',k)
#List to store ray z coordinate data
exponential_procs_lists = []
for ray_n in range(2,rays):
    process_length = 10000
    #Compute data for z layers coordinate
    z_exponential_layers = np.cumsum(np.random.exponential(lam,size = process_length))
    #Cutoff values that lie outside z_max
    cutoff = [x for x in z_exponential_layers if x < z_max]
    #Append 0 at the start of exponential z vector
    if min(cutoff) == 0:
        new1 = np.insert(cutoff,0,0)
    else:
        new1 = cutoff
    #Append z_max at end of exponential z vector
    new2 = np.insert(new1,len(new1),z_max)
    #Append exponential ray z vector to list
    exponential_procs_lists.append(new2)

#Create list that will store random numbers data for each ray
big_list = []
#Loop over every ray, check how many dz lie within each layer and assign random variable (k total times)
for list_n in exponential_procs_lists:
    #Create empty list to store random data for each ray
    vec = []
    #Sum repeats checks that there is k elements in each vector, since k = int(z_max/dz)
    sum_repeats = 0
    #Calculate the intervals between each layers coordinate vector
    list_n_diff  = np.diff(list_n)
    for item in list_n_diff:
        #Calculate how many dz fit inside each interval
        repeats = int(item/dz)
        #Repeat random variable 'repeats' times. This ensures that if we sample x times and each
        #time we are in the same interval, that random variable is repeated
        vec += [np.random.normal(0,1)]*repeats
        #Update sum_repeats to check that there is K elements in the vector
        sum_repeats += repeats
    #Print to check sum_repeats equals k in each running of the whole calculation (we in first loop here)
    print('sum repeats =',sum_repeats)
    print('mean interval size =',np.mean(np.diff(new2)))
    #Append m(z) data to the main list, and repeat for each ray
    #Big list is a list of lists, so we must now transform it into a matrix form (np.array)
    big_list.append(vec)
```

The problem is that when I run this code, the length of each `vec` containing the random variables is not equal to `k` and changes each time. For example one run gives

```
k = 10000
sum repeats = 9507
mean interval size = 0.0992551287849846
sum repeats = 9493
mean interval size = 0.0992551287849846
sum repeats = 9500
mean interval size = 0.0992551287849846
sum repeats = 9500
mean interval size = 0.0992551287849846
sum repeats = 9479
mean interval size = 0.0992551287849846
sum repeats = 9508
mean interval size = 0.0992551287849846
sum repeats = 9509
mean interval size = 0.0992551287849846
sum repeats = 9485
mean interval size = 0.0992551287849846
```

How can I make sure that the number of random elements in each vector is equal to `k`?

Comment: it is because of your cutoff values using `z_max` which obviously reduces the size of `vec`. These are your length of the list `cutoff` `978
979
982
983
1009
1010
1036
1037
1010
1011
962
963
965
966
956
957`

Comment: No, that isn't the problem since the maximum in each list is z_max.

Comment: Why do you think its not the problem? Did you check the length of list `cutoff` I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming dz = 1 for simplicity:

You are generating a list of random numbers (z_exponential_layers) that are always positive and are larger than the one before (cumsum).

Then, you cut off (cutoff) any number above an upper limit(z_max)

Therefore, The numbers in your cutoff list are in the range: (0, z_max) . The open boundaries are because of exp(x) > 0 and the condition of strictly less than z_max.

With this in mind, the values in cutoff are: [z_0, z_1, ..., z_n], where z_0 > 0 and z_n < z_max, and z_(i+1) > z_i

By using np.diff, you are generating a vector of each of the differences in the range (0, z_max), and the sum of all these values is equal to (z_n - z_0), which is by logic smaller than z_max.

Add the fact that you are truncating the differences (by using int(item/dz)), you increase the inequality:

repeats = z_n - z_0 - round_down_loss < z_max.

So, in order to get repeats = z_max, you need to make z_0 = 0 (i.e., insert a 0 if min(cutoff) > 0). And then, your result is going to be
repeats = z_n - z_0 - round_down_loss = z_n - round_down_loss < z_max

If you remove the rounding, you get that:

repeats = z_n, which is still less than z_max.

If your randomly generated increments (using np.exponential) become infinitesimally small, then you can have that asymptotically:

repeats -> z_max

With that in mind, I propose the following corrections:

```
if min(cutoff) > 0:  # Instead of equal
    new1 = np.insert(cutoff,0,0)
else:
    new1 = cutoff
...
for item in list_n_diff:
    #Calculate how many dz fit inside each interval
    repeats = item/dz  # remove int because it truncates the values
```